# Objective-C send parameter to void function

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code that I'm using to store an image in an iOS app after taking a picture with the camera.  The image needs to have an identifiable name so it can later be retrieved for each contact.  How can I pass it a parameter or two so that the filename will end up being something like firstname_lastname.jpg instead of newImage.jpg?

```
  -(void)saveIMAGE {

    NSData *imgView = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0);

    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];

    imgPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newImage.jpg"];

    [imgView writeToFile:imgPathString atomically:NO];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Image Saved" message:@"The Image Was Saved." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]; [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Can someone at least explain the down votes so I at least know what I'm doing wrong in asking my question?

Comment: Use like:`- (void)saveImage:(NSString *)imageName{
...
imgPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
...
}`

Comment: Each downvoter has their own reason. Probably one of the reasons will be it's a very basic question.

Comment: The downvotes are because it appears you've made no effort to find the answer yourself first. There are countless Objective-C tutorials that cover such simple basic of the language.

Comment: I've searched all over, perhaps I just wasn't googling the correct terminology as I have just begun programming in objc. Thanks for the response.

Comment: From what I had found I was reading that it wasn't possible, which seemed absurd, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this line

```
imgPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.jpg",firstname,lastName]];
```

Modify your method like:

```
- (void) saveImage :(NSString *)firstname withLastName :(NSString *)lastName
{

      NSData *imgView = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0);

      NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];

      imgPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.jpg",firstname,lastName]];

      [imgView writeToFile:imgPathString atomically:NO];

       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Image Saved" message:@"The Image Was Saved." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [alert show];

}
```

and just change the call to

```
[self saveImage:@"Scott" withLastName:@"Rowley"];
```

Comment: I ran the call with variables but it's running great, thanks again.
[self saveImage:artist_Name withLastName:artist_LastName];